# Xamarin WebView showing Blank Page when using Local Network with HTTPS

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin-live-player

I have a `<WebView Source="https://192.168.5.32:3000/"/>`

showing a React app with these URLS

```
You can now view my-app in the browser.

Local:            https://localhost:3000/
On Your Network:  https://192.168.5.32:3000/
```

It needs to be HTTPS.

The problem is that if it's `HTTPS` url from the local network when I debug using `Xamarin Live Player` the app shows only blank page. If I try with `HTTP` on local network or any other site with `HTTPS` it works.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Since Emulators and USB are not an option for specific reasons, what else can I use ?

Comment: @SushiHangover Android 8.1 (or you mean something else with platform, I dont have much experience with mobile dev). I'm using virtual machine and emulator is so slooow I've waited for it and it stays blank too.

Comment: Yes I can access `https://192.168.5.32:3000/` from the Android devcie's Browser, but wrapped in the Xamarin's WebView it stays blank screen. I'm not using `localhost`.

Comment: Implement the onReceivedError/onReceivedSslError and check out whats wrong. You can get more information with the WebResourceError/SslError parameters. It could be also a problem where the webview only opens URLs on port 80 and not on other ones.

Comment: I just hosted the website in Azure and im using it from there.